# Multiple Group By Categories

Tags: grouping

I have the following columns in the list. I want to create a view where items are grouped in the following manner:

1st grouping by State|| Another column that shows grouping by Sector || Another column that shows grouping by Current Vendor

I want this view within the same view as opposed to creating 3 different views with the respective groupings.

I can't seem to open SharePoint designer. Is there a OOTB SP functionality to create this view?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** there's no OOTB functionality in SharePoint to achieve a group by function with *more that **two** columns* , but you can achieve this using the SharePoint designer & `dataview` web part.
For more details on how to achieve group by with SP designer please check the below link: 
  http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/05/group-by-more-than-2-columns-sharepoint.html